# Single Player or Local Multiplayer?

Tags: terraria

I've heard there are several differences between playing single player and being the only player on a multiplayer server. For example, more items can exist lying on the ground before they despawn, and some bugs exist on one platform but not the other.

If I'm playing by myself, are there any tactical advantages to playing on one over another?

Comment: None that I have ever seen. Will be interesting to see what this question may come up with. I know there are differences in hosting through the games UI vs hosting in a dedicated server but not single player vs multi-player.

Comment: I have never heard any of this before. Can you post where you 'heard' about these gameplay differences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both SP and Multiplayer have pros and cons.

In single player, unless you have a hacked client, you have no 'server commands.' However, it has the least amount of lag.

On the other hand, multiplayer, assuming you have a normal server handed out, allows you to change the time, which can be useful if you are just starting out and don't want to face a ton of zombies when it's getting late, or can't wait for your first boss fight and just want it to be night time already. Not to mention, it can be easy to get a free Tshock server, which allows you more freedom, including the ability to spawn items.

Note, though, that if you do Multiplayer with a bad computer it may lag your computer. If time or items don't interest you and you just want to play Terraria, stick with Single Player.
The server can also die without saving if you simply close it down, or if it crashes. Make sure to use exit command when you are done and it's a good idea to save often

However, on a side note- You should play through all of Terraria before spawning in items with Tshock, just so you can have fun with it, or else spawn your items while having a SP.

Comment: If playing a "Hardcore" character,  Local Multiplayer would allow you to re-enter the world after a death and attempt to recover lost items.  In Single Player your only option is to let your ghost gaze longingly at the items that will be destroyed as you exit the game....

Answer (score 0):

Well in singleplayer there isn't any lag, but you can't spawn any items via commands. And on multiplayer you can spawn items and lots of other commands. But sometimes the server crashes without saving.